# Disable node discovery in a single node cluster on Elasticsearch managed cloud

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-cloud

I am using a dedicated single-node cluster for monitoring and logs on Elasticsearch managed cloud.

For this cluster, I keep getting warning logs indicating I should disable node discovery since I am using a single-node cluster.

How can this be done?
Remember, this is Elasticsearch managed cloud so I cannot edit configuration files directly.

Full warning log:

`This node is a fully-formed single-node cluster with cluster UUID [*******************], but it is configured as if to discover other nodes and form a multi-node cluster via the [discovery.seed_hosts=[<some IP>:<some port>]] setting. Fully-formed clusters do not attempt to discover other nodes, and nodes with different cluster UUIDs cannot belong to the same cluster. The cluster UUID persists across restarts and can only be changed by deleting the contents of the node's data path(s). Remove the discovery configuration to suppress this message.`

Comment: How did you set up your single node cluster on Elastic cloud? I just set up a one zone one node cluster and `discovery.seed_hosts` is empty as it should be. Can you show what you get from running `GET _cluster/settings?include_defaults&filter_path=**.discovery` ?

Comment: After executing `GET _cluster/settings?include_defaults&filter_path=**.discovery` I got:

`
{
  "defaults": {
    "discovery": {
      "seed_hosts": [
        "<some IP>:<some port>"
      ],
      ...
}`

Comment: Bck to my initial question: How did you set up your single node cluster on Elastic cloud?

Comment: I created a single node, single zone, 1GB ES deployment. I scaled ES instance to 2GB.
EDIT: After deployment restart (with downtime) discovery setting correctly set to blank. I will it as answer if it proves to be a durable solution.

Comment: Ok great, glad you figured it out!

Comment: The solution was to restart the whole deployment (with downtime).
After that, the discovery setting was setup correctly for single node, single zone deployment.

Comment: Interesting, not sure how you landed in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to restart the whole deployment (with downtime). After that, the discovery setting was setup correctly for single node, single zone deployment.